# Type inference difference for find method between normal directory and Nest project in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I wrote two similar codes, one in a normal directory and another one in a nest Project

```
//Normal Directory
class Car{
    id: number;
}

let Carslist: Car[] = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}];

function getbyID(arg:number){
    let result = Carslist.find((elem) =>elem.id == arg);
    console.log(result)
}
```

```
//Nest Project
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Car } from './car';
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
    Carslist: Car[] = [];
 
    getbyID(arg:number){
        let result = this. Carslist.find((elem) =>elem.id == arg);
        console.log(result);
    }  
}
```

In the first code the type of `result` is Car | undefined whereas in the second code the type of `result` is Car instead of Car | undefined, what is the issue?

Comment: Can you make sure that your projects have the same tsconfig?

Comment: @wonderflame how do i check the tsconfig for a normal directory? i just made a directory and  added a ts file

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: Open command panel and type `Typescript: Go to Project Configuration`

Comment: I assume in your nest project you have `strict` tsconfig compiler option disabled. If you enable it you will get `Car | undefined`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @wonderflame yes i added ```    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,``` and it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is the difference between Typescript configuration. I suspect that in "Normal Directory" you have [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) compiler option enabled, which guarantees more strict type checking. `strict` compiler option enables all options of this family:

```
alwaysStrict
strictNullChecks
strictBindCallApply
strictFunctionTypes
strictPropertyInitialization
noImplicitAny
noImplicitThis
useUnknownInCatchVariables
```

You can either enable all of them or enable the one that actually is responsible for this difference, which is `strictNullChecks`.

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks):

> When `strictNullChecks` is `false`, `null` and `undefined` are effectively ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at runtime. When `strictNullChecks` is `true`, `null` and `undefined` have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected. For example with this TypeScript code, `users.find` has no guarantee that it will actually find a user, but you can write code as though it will:

```
declare const loggedInUsername: string;
 
const users = [
  { name: "Oby", age: 12 },
  { name: "Heera", age: 32 },
];
 
const loggedInUser = users.find((u) => u.name === loggedInUsername);
console.log(loggedInUser.age);
```

> Setting `strictNullChecks` to `true` will raise an error that you have not made a guarantee that the `loggedInUser` exists before trying to use it.